# Can you enter binary data in Windows command line?

Tags: windows, binary, windows-console

Let's say that I am running a console application that takes input from the user.

Is there a way to send binary data to the program, for example can I send the following three bytes to the program:

```
0x80 0xF4 0x12
```

Comment: The console input buffer is Unicode (UTF-16) text, and programs can read it either directly as Unicode (e.g. `ReadConsoleW`) or encoded to a system codepage (e.g. `ReadConsoleA`, `ReadFile`). An application that needs the user to input arbitrary bytes should read them in a form such as `"\x80\xf4\x12"` or simply "80f412", or a common plaintext format such as base64.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to send binary data to the program

If you have numeric keyboard block, then you can try using [ALT codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code): <kbd>ALT</kbd> + `4 digits keycode`, i.e. <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> should give you `w`. But this method got [many limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Problems) and is pretty user unfriendly.

You should rather ask user if s/he wants to enter some codes and then let him enter i.e. string 0x0ff which then you convert to the value it represents.